# explain count(*) in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

In SQL, i know the use of select * which basically means selecting all rows but what does count(*) do and how does it work?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_count

Comment: select * which basically means selecting all rows  - No it means select all columns the number of rows returned is determined by WHERE conditions and JOIN conditions.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly well documented here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_count

> Returns a count of the number of non-NULL values of expr in the rows retrieved by a SELECT statement. The result is a BIGINT value.
>
> If there are no matching rows, COUNT() returns 0. COUNT(NULL) returns 0.

Comment: Also very well covered on this site in other reference questions.